# automatic unzipping rar files in pages

Tags: php, mysql

Hi frnds i am uploading the files  suppose if i download one file from my webpage that should automatically unzip and go to table how i can do that can anyone help me out thanks in advance

Comment: Friends accept friends' answers.

Comment: And your question is extremely unclear - are you uploading or downloading files? What does "go to table" mean?

Comment: Lavanya, you've admitted in previous questions that you have no idea how to accept answers or vote. While I find this extremely hard to believe, as StackOverflow's interface is as simple and intuitive as it gets, why not ask that question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution how to unpack rar archives with PHP that the answer it to take a look at the [RAR extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.rar.php) for PHP.